# what are the restrictions on pandas dataframes being written to_feather?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataframe I want to keep on disk, to avoid regenerating it frequently.  `to_excel` is quite slow to write it out.  I understood that `to_feather` would be a faster write/read and smaller file.

However I can't get it to work.  First it complained because I had a multi-index.  So I reset that to flatten it.

Now it's complaining:

```
ArrowTypeError: ('an integer is required (got type str)', 'Conversion failed for column CFT_Code with type object')
```

I have a range of `dtypes` in my dataframe:

```
set([complete_df[col].dtype for col in complete_df.columns])
{dtype('<M8[ns]'), dtype('int64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('O')}
```

It's just a dataframe of numbers, dates, and plenty of empty cells.

Am I misundertstanding the use of the feather files?  I don't think I have an unusual dataframe.  If this is inappropriate use,  is there a better (in terms of speed and file size) format that I should save to?

=====

I find that writing/reading  `to_pickle` file is quite quicker than, at least, `to_excel` or `to_csv`.   Would still like to understand, though, what's the deal with `to_feather`